# Как удалить все optinons из select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую `selectize.js` для модификации выпадающего списка. При выборе пункта в марках авто, аяксом грузится опции для списка Сервисных центров. Все приходит правильно, и аякс работатет, но вот проблема в том что почему то остаются опции от предыдущих выборов, как очистить все опции из списка сто перед отправкой аякса?

```js
/*выбор МАРКи АВТО*/
var $selectAuto = $('.js-select').selectize({});

/*выбор СЕРВИСНЫЙ ЦЕНТР*/
var $selectService = $('.js-select-services').selectize({
  labelField: 'name',
  valueField: 'value',
  render: {
    option: function(data) {
      //console.log(data);                        
      return '<div data-value="' + data.value + '" data-selectable class="option">' + data.text + '</div>';
    },
    item: function(data) {
      //console.log(data);                        
      return '<div data-value="' + data.value + '" data-selectable class="option">' + data.text + '</div>';
    }
  }
});

var $selectServiceSelectize = $selectService[0].selectize;
var $selectAutoSelectize = $selectAuto[0].selectize;

$selectAutoSelectize.on('change', function(value) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax/salons.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      brand: value
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $selectServiceSelectize.load(function(callback) {

        $.each(response, function(value, text) {
          callback([{
            text: text,
            value: value
          }]);
        });
      });
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<select name="brand" id="type-cars" class="js-select" data-typecars="all" size="1" name="form_text_<?=$arResult[" QUESTIONS "]["BRAND "]["STRUCTURE "][0]["ID "]?>">
  <option value="" data-type="">Выберете марку</option>
  <? $res=C IBlockSection::GetList(array( "SORT"=>"ASC"), array("IBLOCK_ID" => 40, "ACTIVE" => "Y"), false, array("ID", "NAME"), false); while ($ob = $res->GetNext()) { ?>
  <option value="<?=$ob[" NAME "]?>" data-type="type-cars">
    <?=$ob[ "NAME"]?>
  </option>
  <? } ?>
</select>

<label class="title-label" for="">сервисный центр</label>
<!-- <input class="input-form" type="text"> -->
<select name="services" id="type-services" class="js-select-services" data-typecars="all" size="1" name="form_text_<?=$arResult[" QUESTIONS "]["SERVICE_CENTER "]["STRUCTURE "][0]["ID "]?>">
  <option value="" data-type="">Выберете марку</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если судить по [этому вопросу и ответам к нему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923751/how-to-clear-a-selected-value-selectize-js-dopdown-drop) то вам надо вызвать `$selectServiceSelectize.clear()` перед отправкой AJAX. Т.е. будет что-то такое:

```
$selectAutoSelectize.on('change', function(value) {
  $selectServiceSelectize.clear();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax/salons.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      brand: value
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $selectServiceSelectize.load(function(callback) {

        $.each(response, function(value, text) {
          callback([{
            text: text,
            value: value
          }]);
        });
      });
    }
  })
})
```